# mocking the return value of domainInstance.validate()

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I am writing a [spock](http://spockframework.org) unit test that tests a controller method.

The controller action under test instantiates a new domain instance object and
calls validate on it before it saves.
Is there anyway of mocking the call to domainInstance.validate() so I
can make it return whatever I want? Or do I have to hide this
instanciation and saving behind a service method to achieve this?

I do this this way, because within the context of a unit test for a
controller, the constraints of a domain object should not be involved.
I test those elsewhere (in the MyDomainClassTests, obviously). If I
wanted to take those into into account my test would be an integration
test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I have come to the conclusion that what I wanted is rather tricky. If you're in a scenario where you don't *have* to use `mockDomain()`, you could add a groovy metaclass method and it's implementation (return true or false, whichever you want)

If you *do* need mockDomain() because you need to mock pre-existing instances you are out of options, at least for now because mockDomain() and fiddling with metaclass methods that mockDomain actually provides will not mix.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't place the validate on the domain instance itself, but rather in a service, 
you could let your controller take a Service in its constructor (or rather an interface of a service). Let that service handle the validation.

Now for your unittest of that controller, you would pass in a Mock of that interface(service) to the controller and configure the mock to return whatever you want.

For .net i can recommend Moq (http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Comment: well yes that is the alternative solution i suggested when writing "Or do I have to hide this instanciation and saving behind a service method to achieve this?" The problem would be that I would be bypassing what is core grails functionality and sort of working against the spirit of the framework

Comment: Right, i didn't see the tags (either i'm going blind for some reason *cough* or you just added them - i hope the later). If you can't remove the dependency to the validate you're stuck. Some mocking frameworks *might* do wonder - did you try TypeMock Isolator?

Comment: (EDIT: TypeMock is for .net and c++ but i don't know if there are similar alternatives to grails/java?)

Comment: Sorry per, i think the tags where already there :) Anyway, yes there is a bunch of testing frameworks for groovy/grails, one of which i am using (Spock) I don't have a lot of experience with them, I have been in the Java/mockito camp over the past few years.

Comment: btw if you can add the 'spock' tag here that would be great. with my score i can't add non-existing tags yet :)